# how to import vscode path

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am receiving the following error from vscode when i try to edit a go file:

"Error loading workspace: You are outside of a module and outside of $GOPATH/src. If you are using modules, please open your editor to a directory in your module. If you believe this warning is incorrect, please file an issue: [https://github.com/golang/go/issues/new."](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/new.%22)

My go path is set as follows:
GOPATH=C:\Users\myusername\go

I have vscode and go working together just fine on other machines... but i cant figure out what is wrong here.

I am still new to go so i am a little confused as to what the point of the GOPATH is.

from the go docs its says: "The GOPATH environment variable specifies the location of your workspace"

and the for the definition of a workspace the docs say: "A workspace is a directory hierarchy with two directories at its root: "

so from what the docs are saying and what vscode is complaining about is that i have my code outside of the path "C:\Users\myusername\go"...

obviously go doesn't expect me to do all my work in the location "C:\Users\myusername\go" on my machine.

so what is it complaining about?

here is the output of my "gopls -rpc.trace -v check go_practice.go" command:

```
2021/04/21 16:05:23 Info:2021/04/21 16:05:23 go env for C:\projects\go_practice
(root C:\projects\go_practice)
(go version go version go1.16.3 windows/amd64)
(valid build configuration = false)
(build flags: [])
GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
GOFLAGS=
GOINSECURE=
GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
GO111MODULE=
GOCACHE=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\go-build
GONOPROXY=
GOMOD=NUL
GOPRIVATE=
GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\username\go\pkg\mod
GONOSUMDB=
GOPATH=C:\Users\username\go
```

Answer (score 27):

Maybe you have opened a directory with the following format in VSCode.

```
example dir
      |- project1
           |- main.go
           |- go.mod
           ...
      |- project2
           |- main.go
           |- go.mod
           ...
      |- project3
           |- main.go
           |- go.mod
           ...
...
```

Opening a directory containing multiple go.mod files will result in this error.
The solution is to open only the project1 directory in VSCode, with only one go.mod file open.

Comment: Now the Golang support workspace, we can open several modules! Refer to https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md

Answer (score 18):

If you have multiple go.mod file in one workspace, you can use the "go work" to add the folder.

it need Go 1.18+

1. In the root path of the workspace
2. $go work init
3. $go work use [folder-name]

The go.work file will be generated automatically

example:

```
go work init
go work http_Todo <no need "./">
```

In the following is my testing project structure for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can initialize a so-called "go module" by running `go mod init <name>`, where name, usually, is your repository URL. (eg. github.com/user/repo)

This will generate a `go.mod` file. Read more about go modules [here](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules).

Comment: Thanks. But why do i have to do this? i have another machine where i have used vscode and go multiple times and i never had to do this?

Comment: @matt You have to use Go modules because use of Go modules are manadory. Read and stick to https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started. Just do it.

Comment: ah. ok. i think that throw me off was that go modules seem to be a newer thing.. i went through the whole "The Go Programming Language" book and they were never mentioned... so i thought they not important or some peculiarity with vscode.. but now i see how they are an essential part of the Go's dependancy management system. Thank!

Comment: "just do it" is not an answer to why

Answer (score 1):

Working on go 1.19, what solved this issue for me is to put

`export GO111MODULE=ON`

on ~/.bash_profile file.

Make sure you restart vscode.

If you want to debug with vscode, make sure to put in your launch.json file

```
 "configurations": [
    {
        ......
        "env": {  
            "GO111MODULE": "on",
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you should open directly open your project by vs-code not a parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

initializing Go modules fixed my issue

```
   Go mod init projname
```

Answer (score 0):

If you came here googling for this error:

> error loading workspace you are outside of a module and outside of $GOPATH/src

This may mean that you have multiple `go.mod` files in this folder, and the Go extension refuses to work. You'll either have to remove these files (by renaming, perhaps), or initialize a [multi-module go workspace](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces)